# Disabling Video Recording

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, video-recording, disable

We are developing an application which mainly deals with videos. How can we prevent these two problems:

1) the video gets recorded when screen recording enabled in the device
  2) recording the video using another device

How can we prevent or disable it in both android and ios devices?

Comment: `recording the video using another device` how would you like to prevent this ?

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please mark it Correct/Approved. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent taking screenshot and screen recorder functionality by using

Java:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

Kotlin:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

in your activity.

**NOTE:** You cannot any how restrict user from clicking picture or recording your app from any other device. So, you can use above line and prevent such scenario. Thanks.